# Calculadora de comision

Tags: javascript

quisiera que me ayuden con una solución, busco que al introducir un valor en el input, se muestre automáticamente en comisión, solo el 9% del equivalente el valor del input, y en el "te depositamos" la resta del input con la comisión, esa es mi lógica, pero no me sale

[image: HTML]
[image: JS]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no pongas imágenes con código: copia y pega el código directamente. Te han tenido que salir avisos mientras creabas la pregunta dándote consejos, pero igualmente puedes consular [ask] y leer el [tour] de bienvenida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que te falta código, ya que haces lo que seria el calculo de la comisión y luego mostras únicamente dicha comisión y mismo en la consulta dijiste que te interesaba mostrar el saldo - comisión, por lo tanto ahí te faltaría eso, por otro lado no es necesario que pongas function per en el método del objeto

```
var ops ={
    percentage: function per(valor){
        return (parseInt(valor) *0.09)
    }
}
```

con que lo pongas asi ya funciona:

```
var ops ={
    percentage(valor){
        return (parseInt(valor) *0.09)
    }
}
```

te dejo el código en base a lo que entendí que quieres hacer.

```js
var ops ={
    percentage: function (valor){
        return (parseInt(valor) *0.09)
    }
}

function enviarYCalcular(){
    let saldo = document.getElementById("saldo").value
    let comision = ops.percentage(saldo)

    document.getElementById("comision")
        .innerHTML = '<span style="color: green;">'+ comision +'</span>'
    document.getElementById("deposito")
    .innerHTML = '<span style="color: green;">'+ (saldo - comision) +'</span>'
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="services" class="services">
        <div class="container">
            <form class="calc">
                <h2>Saldo Disponible en tu Tarjeta</h2>
                <input type="number" id="saldo">
                <p>Comision con CreditCash (9%)</p>
                <p id="comision"></p>
                <p>Te depositamos</p>
                <h1 id="deposito"></h1>
                <button type="button" onclick="enviarYCalcular()">enviar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias, como sería si quisiera que se muestre automáticamente pongo el numero, sin necesidad de presionar un button